# Sagemaker can't find paths in container

Tags: python, docker, amazon-sagemaker

This is a hard situation to describe.

I have a python model train script at:

`myproject/opt/program/train`

This gets a file at `./opt/ml/input/data/external/train.csv`

When I do `python3 opt/program/train` the training runs fine locally.

Then I containerize the project and copy `opt` to `/opt` in my Dockerfile.

Now when I run `docker run <image name> train` it also trains fine.

Then I deploy the image to SageMaker, create an estimator, and call `model.fit(my_data)` I get:

`Exception during training: [Errno 2] File b'./opt/ml/input/data/external/train.csv' does not exist`

It's definitely there, I was able to train by running the container myself.  Also running the container and exploring the file system I can find the file.

So I think I have some filesystem misunderstanding.  From the root of the container, all of these seem to have equivalent outputs.

```
root@798ffe7364c6:/# ls opt
ml  program
root@798ffe7364c6:/# ls /opt
ml  program
root@798ffe7364c6:/# ls ./opt
ml  program
```

I'm trying to come up with a way to have one path that will work locally, in the container, and on AWS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was missing the fact that SageMaker looks for your data channels in S3 and copies those to your container at `/opt/ml/input/data`

By default it seems to use `training` and `validation` as the channel names.  Therefore, in my example above, it would have never copied data from my `external` folder on S3 to the right `external` folder in my container.  In fact, I discovered it was copying it instead to `/opt/ml/input/data/training/external/train.csv`.

To resolve this, I would have either had to change my folder names, or use `InputDataConfig` to define other channels.  I chose the later and was able to get it working.

More info on `InputDataConfig` here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_CreateTrainingJob.html